# Permission denied when running script/server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just cloned the [mini_fb_demo](http://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb_demo) from Github, went into the directory and ran `script/server`, and got this error:

```
-bash: script/server: Permission denied
```

I've been using script/server like this for other projects for awhile, and this has never happened. What is causing this? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you do a ls -l in your rails and script directories?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably don't have execute permission on `script/server`.

Try: `chmod +x script/server` then start it again.